# Mostrar parte del valor que devuelve un JSON con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un array de objeto que me devuelve esto:

```
Array = [
{
 0: "46140:ADEMUZ"
 1: "46729:ADOR"
 2: "46940:AEROPUERTO DE MANISES (VALENCIA)"
 3: "46890:AGULLENT"
 4: "46176:AHILLAS"}
]
```

Me gustaría mostrar solo una parte del valor:

```
Array = [
{
 0: "46140"
 1: "46729"
 2: "46940"
 3: "46890"
 4: "46176"}
]
```

Estoy utilizando `fetch` para hacer la llamada al archivo que tengo en local, no sé si es la forma de hacerlo, ya que no llevo mucho con javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    mostrar()

});


function mostrar() {

    fetch('/46xcodpos.txt')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(content => {
            let lines = content.split(/\n/);
            console.log(lines);
            recorrer(lines)
        });
}


function recorrer(lines) {
    //Iterar sobre el arreglo
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');


    lines.forEach(muestra => {

        resultado.innerHTML += `
 
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-6 card m-2 p-2">
 
                    <div class="list-group">
                   
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">${muestra}</a>
                  </div>
                    </div>
 
                `;
    }


    )
};
```

Comment: ¿Y que ha intentado? considere: [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola, lo he intentado con JSON.stringify() pasandole el iterador, pero solo me devuelve números sueltos, es decir de `0: "46140:ADEMUZ"` le paso: ```const cambio = JSON.stringify(lines);
            console.log(cambio[9]); ``` solo me devuelve un valor suelto.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` convierte un objeto en una cadena con formato `json`. Luego, cuando pides `cambio[9]` realmente estás accediendo al carácter en la posición 9 de dicha cadena.

Comment: eso ya lo se gracias. Alguna pista de `.substr` no aclaración del concepto sino ejemplo que puedan resolver el problema especificado más arriba. gracias de nuevo.

Comment: ¿Una variable para la cadena de números? ¿o una para da número? ¿El array siempre tiene un solo objeto? En el ejemplo pones una cadena pero pides guardar "el" número del principio.

Comment: No se lie, usted puede ver el json más arriba. el valor que devuelve es una string: `0: "46140:ADEMUZ"` de ahi me gustaría mostrar solo: `0: "46140"` lo entiendes? sabria aportar algo de luz?  pd: (acabo de editar la pregunta, disculpa si no fui lo suficiente claro)muchas gracias.

Comment: Vale, pues vuelve a editar tu pregunta y agrega tu intento fallido (el que pusiste en el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477031/como-guardar-los-n%c3%bameros-de-un-valor-de-un-json#comment849123_477031)) , mientras, te preparo una respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de obtener el resultado que muestras en tu pregunta, a partir de la información que tienes, sería usando el método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) aplicado sobre el `Array` original y un bucle [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para recorrer las claves del objeto.

Una vez que tienes acceso al valor de cadena, de cada clave, puedes usar el método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) sobre dicho valor para separar la cadena usando como separador el carácter `:` que viene incluido en la misma, luego basta con tomar el elemento de la posición 0 del `Array` devuelto por dicho método `split()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    0: "46140:ADEMUZ",
    1: "46729:ADOR",
    2: "46940:AEROPUERTO DE MANISES (VALENCIA)",
    3: "46890:AGULLENT",
    4: "46176:AHILLAS"
  }
];

let arrCambiado = arr.map(objeto => {
  // creamos un nuevo objeto para no modificar
  // el objeto del array original
  let nuevoObjeto = {}
  for(let clave in objeto) {
    let nuevoValor = objeto[clave].split(':')[0];
    nuevoObjeto[clave] = nuevoValor;
  }
  return nuevoObjeto;
});

console.log(arrCambiado);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si analizamos el código de la siguiente linea:

```js
let nuevoValor = objeto[clave].split(':')[0];
```

estamos obteniendo el valor con `objeto[clave]`.

Suponiendo que el valor obtenido es: `"46140:ADEMUZ"`, estamos aplicando sobre este valor el método `split(':')`, que separa dicha cadena en un `Array` que contiene 2 elementos: `"46140"` y `"ADEMUZ"`. Luego, estamos devolviendo el primero de dichos elementos: `[0]`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let cadena = "46140:ADEMUZ";

let arr = cadena.split(':');

let valor = arr[0];

console.log(valor);

// la siguiente linea hace lo mismo que las 3 anteriores
console.log(cadena.split(':')[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola Mauricio! no me dio tiempo a poner en mi pregunta la manera que lo estoy haciendo. estoy utilizando fetch para hacer la llamada desde el archivo local tipo .txt. disculpa por no haberlo expuesto antes. Muchas gracias de antemano